# How can I calculate this limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim _{ m\rightarrow \infty  }{ \left( \lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \cos ^{ 2n }{ \left( \pi m!x \right)  }  }  \right)  } $

**Attempt** :  since $\cos ^{ 2 }{ x=\frac { 1+cos2x }{ 2 }  } $ so we can write $$\lim _{ m\rightarrow \infty  }{ \left( \lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \cos ^{ 2n }{ \left( \pi m!x \right)  }  }  \right)  } =\lim _{ m\rightarrow \infty  }{ \left( \lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { \left( 1+cos\left( 2\pi m!x \right)  \right) ^{ n } }{ 2^{ n } }  }  \right)  } $$ 
then i applied Teylor expansion for $cos\left( 2\pi m!x \right)$
$$cox\left( 2\pi m!x \right) =1-\frac { \left( 2\pi m!x \right) ^{ 2 } }{ 2! } +o\left( \frac { \left( 2\pi m!x \right) ^{ 4 } }{ 4! }  \right)   $$ 
but this way seems me very long,how can i proceed?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: nice question from the good old Hardy's Pure Mathematics. +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let 
\begin{equation*}
f_{m}(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }(\cos m!\pi x)^{2n}.
\end{equation*}
Note that for $m$ fixed, $f_{m}(x)$ is the limit of geometric sequence, $%
r^{n}$ with 
\begin{equation*}
r=(\cos m!\pi x)^{2}\in \lbrack 0,1].
\end{equation*}
If $r=1,$ the limit of the geometric sequence $(r^{n})$ is $1,$ otherwise,
the limit is $0.$ So when $m!x$ is an integer $f_{m}(x)=1,$ and otherwise
(when $m!x$ is not integer) $f_{m}(x)=0.$ Now let 
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty }f_{m}(x).
\end{equation*}
Let us discuss when $x$ is rational or is irrational. If $x$ is irrational,
then 
\begin{equation*}
(\cos m!\pi x)^{2}\neq 1
\end{equation*}
and then $f(x)=0.$ If $x$ is rational, say $x=\frac{a}{b}$ with $a$ and $b$
integers. We have 
\begin{equation*}
m!x=\frac{m!a}{b}=\frac{1\times 2\times \cdots \times m\times a}{b}.
\end{equation*}
If $m\geq b$ then $f(x)=1.$ It follows that 
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty }\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }(\cos m!\pi x)^{2n}=0
\end{equation*}
if $x$ is irrational 
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty }\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }(\cos m!\pi x)^{2n}=1
\end{equation*}
if $x$ is instead rational.

Comment: Good answer with nice explanation. +1

Answer (score 0):

The inner limit does not exists; for $x=0$ it's value is $1$ and for $x=\frac{1}{2m!}$ is $0$.

And of course taking the limit of something that does not exist (I'm talking about the outer limit now) is not particularly meaningful

Comment: so the answer is "limit doesn't exist"?

Comment: Yes. Maybe the question in your textbook was phrased differently, I don't know. But that limit does not exists :)

Comment: No general limit exists, but if you break it up into two distinct cases, then a limit exists for each of them. In this case, it's an indicator function (see Idris's answer).

Comment: The limit of inner function exists and depends on both $m$ and $x$. See Idris answer.

Comment: Let me explain how @Ant concludes that the limit does not exists. For $x=0$, $ 
\cos (m!\pi (0))=1$ so the inner limit is 1. But he mention for $x=\frac{1}{2m!}$, $\cos (m!\pi (\frac{1}{2m!}))=0$ so the inner limit is $0.$ 

The confusion is that the inner limit is with respect to $n$ so $x=\frac{1}{2m!}$ is a fixed point when $n$ tends to infinity. His reasoning would be
correct if it was $x_{n}$ converging to $zero$ with $n$ and $\cos (m!\pi
x_{n})=0.$