# Prove a limit equal to Dirichlet function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Prove that $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\cos^{2n}(\pi m!x))=\left\{\begin{matrix} 1,x\in\mathbb{Q}\\ 0, x\in\mathbb{I}\end{matrix}\right.$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I calculate this limit?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1345083/how-can-i-calculate-this-limit)